# Django Channels Send Msg (Hyperlink)

Tags: django, hyperlink, django-channels

I studied Django Channels

The chat room has been established

But i have a problem now

If the client sends a `http://` message

How to make the http message displayed in the chat room have a hyperlink function?

Should it be processed on the front-end or on the back-end?

Comment: Processing it on the backend would mean that the backend sends HTML to the frontend, and the frontend blindly inserts HTML into the DOM. That's a bad idea in general, not only because it's a potential security risk, but also because it assumes the frontend will always want HTML. So, it should definitely be processed on the frontend.

Comment: ok, so the front-end detects whether the received message has a string of `http://`, and then processes it and converts it into a hyperlink.

Comment: you could have the backend detect things like this, convert the message into markdown and send that to the client and use one of the many JS markdown views on the client to display this. Just make sure you do not permit custom tags only regular markdown.

Comment: @MatthausWoolard ok, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Front-end processing will be better, and the front-end uses markdown.